# How can I add menu items when importing nodes into Drupal 7 (with the Feeds module)?

Tags: 7, routes, feeds, importing-exporting

I'm importing a site using the Feeds module, and I do not see any way to specify which nodes should get a menu item.  How can I do this?

If the Feeds module cannot do this, is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the sandbox project [Feeds Menu](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/attisan/2144379)

> Adds mapping elements for menu entries for [feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds)